# Unity LocationServices not working on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, location-services

I have a `Unity 5.5.1f1` project that I am attempting to use the `LocaitonServices` to get the users current GPS Location. I am testing this script on physical android and iOS devices. `LocationServices` is returning a location when running the project on Android, but on `iOS 10.2.1` it never returns a location. Is there anything specific that needs to enabled to use the device location on iOS? I am using the `TestLocationService` script from [Location Service Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.Start.html):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestLocationService : MonoBehaviour
{
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        // First, check if user has location service enabled
        if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
            yield break;

        // Start service before querying location
        Input.location.Start();

        // Wait until service initializes
        int maxWait = 20;
        while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            maxWait--;
        }

        // Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds
        if (maxWait < 1)
        {
            print("Timed out");
            yield break;
        }

        // Connection has failed
        if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
        {
            print("Unable to determine device location");
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Access granted and location value could be retrieved
            print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
        }

        // Stop service if there is no need to query location updates continuously
        Input.location.Stop();
    }
}
```

It is saying that `Input.location.isEnabledByUser == false` but Location services are enabled on my device. Note that when opening the app I was never prompted on my iOS device to allow location use, but I was on android.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: are you testing on a device or a simulator?

Comment: @Programmer I have update my answer to add the script that I am calling.

Comment: @JuanBayonaBeriso I am testing on physical android and ios devices.

Comment: Go to settings, select your app and then select 'always' in Location

Comment: same issue,any answers?